# undeclared here (not in a function) in C

Tags: c, hash

im new with c language, but i try to unerstand this quark hashing algorithm that was written in c language, and i found an error while im compiling the source code, from what i understand the WIDTH it already declared, but why is it still error ?

this is the source code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* uncomment to printf execution traces */
// #define DEBUG

#if   defined(UQUARK)
#define CAPACITY 16 
#define RATE      1
#define WIDTH    17
#elif defined(DQUARK)
#define CAPACITY 20
#define RATE      2
#define WIDTH    22
#endif


#define DIGEST WIDTH

typedef uint64_t u64;
typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint8_t   u8; 

typedef struct {
  int pos; /* number of bytes read into x from current block */
  //  u32 x[ WIDTH*8 ]; /* one bit stored in each word */
  u32 x[ WIDTH*8 ]; /* one bit stored in each word */
} hashState;


#if   defined(UQUARK)
/* 17 bytes */
u8 iv[] = {0xd8,0xda,0xca,0x44,0x41,0x4a,0x09,0x97,
       0x19,0xc8,0x0a,0xa3,0xaf,0x06,0x56,0x44,0xdb};
```

and its showing this error

```
quark.c:36:10: error : 'WIDTH' undeclared here (not in a function)
   u32 x[WIDTH*8];
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: The `WIDTH` is defined only when one of `UQUARK` or `DQUARK` is defined. Such control macros are usually set on the command line or in the make file: `gcc -DUQUARK ...` or `cl /DUQUARK ...`.

Comment: To elaborate M.Oehm comment. We will need to see the code file which includes the shown header and the exact way you compile in order to help you with details. Please make a [mcve] which includes the building details. Do you use the make tool? Then show the makefile. Do you use an IDE then list all building parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for some reason neither UQUARK nor DQUARK are defined.

Add this:

```
#if defined(UQUARK) && defined(DQUARK)
#error both UQUARK and DQUARK are defined
#endif

#if !defined(UQUARK) && !defined(dQUARK)
#error Neither UQUARK nor DQUARK are defined
#endif
```

just before following line:

```
#if   defined(UQUARK)
```

Then the compilation will abort if either both `UQUARK` and `DQUARK` are defined (which probably makes no sense) or if neither `UQUARK` nor `DQUARK` are defined (which probably happens in your case).

Now the question is: who defines `UQUARK` and/or `DQUARK`? Only you can tell.